# Installing python package jieba3k changes version of already installed package jieba

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

Here's how to reproduce my issue:

Create a new virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv testenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in testenv/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ source testenv/bin/activate
(testenv) $ cd test
```

Install jieba and check `__version__`:

```
(testenv) test$ pip3 install jieba
Collecting jieba
Installing collected packages: jieba
Successfully installed jieba-0.39
(testenv) test$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 03:28:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jieba
>>> jieba.__version__
'0.39'
>>> Quit (core dumped)
```

Ok, version 0.39.

Install jieba3k:

```
(testenv) test$ pip3 install jieba3k
Collecting jieba3k
Installing collected packages: jieba3k
Successfully installed jieba3k-0.35.1
```

Recheck jieba `__version__`:

```
(testenv) test$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 03:28:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jieba
>>> jieba.__version__
'0.34'
>>> Quit (core dumped)
```

New version is 0.34.

Why is this happening? And how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

`jieba` and `jieba3k` aren't two different packages, they are two different versions of the same package with `jieba` being newer. When you install `jieba3k` it overrides package `jieba` with older version.

In short: forget about `jieba3k`, use only `jieba`.